# xslt to test a set of nodes for value equality

Tags: xslt

Given the following xml:

```
<parameterGroup>
    <parameter value="1" name="Level0_stratum">
    </parameter>
    <parameter value="1" name="Level2_stratum">
    </parameter>
    <parameter value="1" name="Level1_stratum">
    </parameter>
    <parameter value="6" name="foo">
    </parameter>       
    <parameter value="9" name="bar">
    </parameter>    
</parameterGroup>
```

I'd like to derive a boolean variable that indicates whether the @value of ALL the Level*_stratum values are the same, as in this case they are (1).

So far I've been able to group all the pertinent nodes in a set as follows:

```
select="//parameter[starts-with(@name,'Level') and ends-with(@name,'_stratum') ]"
```

but I'm not sure the most efficient way to compare all their @value attributes for equality?

Comment: one way to solve this is for me to write a custom java function; but I'd rather not do this if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you're looking to do (the `value-of` lines are not necessary and are just there to show the values of the variables):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable 
             name="allStrata"
             select="//parameter[starts-with(@name, 'Level') and
                                 ends-with(@name, '_stratum')]" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(count($allStrata), ' strata. ')"/>

      <!-- Determines whether all strata have the same values by comparing them all 
             against the first one. -->
      <xsl:variable name="allStrataEqual" 
                    select="not($allStrata[not(@value = $allStrata[1]/@value)])" />

      <xsl:value-of select="concat('All equal: ', $allStrataEqual)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input above, the result is:

```
3 strata. All equal: true
```

When this is run on your sample input after changing the third `value` to 8 (or anything else), the result is:

```
3 strata. All equal: false
```

Comment: any reason you've changed ends-with to a substring function?

Comment: Simply because `ends-with()` does not exist in XSLT 1.0 and I thought that might be what you are using (I had forgotten that you said you'd already gotten the formula with `ends-with` working).  If the `ends-with` function is available to you, then by all means, that's the better option.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If ends-with() is available then you are using XSLT 2.0, therefore distinct-values() is available, so you can simply do

```
count(distinct-values(
  //parameter[starts-with(@name,'Level') and ends-with(@name,'_stratum') ])/@value))
= 1
```

Comment: there is an errant brace after the ].  Aside from that, this solution has the advantage of returning false when there are no values